# managed object context take too long to load

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm testing performance in my application, to see how it behaves with
a big load of data inside of it. My application is core data based and
uses array controllers in entity mode to fetch data.

What I discovered is that my app fetched all the managed objects
present in core data, so I set the fetch predicate of array
controllers at startup. This reduced dramatically the number of
objects fetched. The problem though is that my app still takes a lot
of time to start when is full of data.

I ran the app within instruments, and the core data fetches instrument
confirms that this is not the problem (my app fetches only 20-30
objects when starts). But running it under Shark I can see that for
4-5 seconds after startup the only call on the stack is to the app
managed object context. So I think it has something to do with
interaction between managed object context and data stored, even if I
don't fetch all the data. If I empty the app or leave little data
inside of it, it starts very quickly.

Does somebody know why this happens? Am I missing something obvious?
Why does it take so much to the managed object context to load if I
only fetch few objects? I always read that core data scales well and
the programming guide states that 10.000 objects are not much for core
data, but in my app it makes a big difference, so I'm wondering where
I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amazing!

Just seconds after asking this questionI find the problem root and solve it !

Just for peoples who may face this problem :

you need to enable **Use Lazy Fetching** at the **Object Controller** for each **NSArray Controller** that you used in your application to solve the performance problem using **core data managed object context**

and here you go !
application starts as fast as you click on it !